# How can I implement an array whose size is not known at compile time in C89?

Tags: c, arrays, c89

Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie to C and was wondering how you could create an array whose size is not known at compile time before the C99 standard was introduced.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Please do not write new software in 1989 C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy.  For example, if you want to create a variable length 1D `int` array, do the following.  First, declare a pointer to type `int`:

```
int *pInt;
```

Next, allocate memory for it.  You should know how many elements you will need (`NUM_INTS`):

```
pInt = malloc(NUM_INTS * sizeof(*pInt));
```

Don't forget to `free` your dynamically allocated array to prevent memory leaks:

```
free(pInt);
```

Comment: ***Big, bold, italic "thanks"*** for suggesting `sizeof(*pointer)` instead of `sizeof(type)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Learned that from you when you yelled at me one day. ;-)

Comment: So that was me... Oh... ;-)

Comment: @FiddlingBits; He almost yelled at every one here :(

Comment: @haccks (If we accept that, it means that almost everyone did something fundamentally wrong then...)

Comment: @haccks Keeping my mouth shut… :-)

Comment: @H2CO3; (No one is perfect except God).

Comment: @haccks Agreed. Everybody proves that fact… repeatedly! lol

Comment: Do malloc takes two arguments?

Comment: @haccks That's right. :)

Comment: @Digital_Reality No just one.  I fixed the typo.

Comment: @FiddlingBits What is the reason to use `sizeof(*ptr)` instead of `sizeof(type)`? Could you provide a link please?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Oh, is that because if you change the type of a variable, you don't need to change your `sizeof` code if you had written it as `sizeof(*ptr)` right? Is this the reason?

Comment: @Utku Correct! You may introduce a subtle bug if you change the type of the variable, but not what you're using `sizeof` on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `malloc` function from `stdlib.h` to create a dynamic array object.

Answer (score 1):

the ordinary way would be to allocate the data on the heap

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  void myfun(unsigned int n) {
    mytype_t*array = (mytype_t*)malloc(sizeof(mytype_t) * n);
    // ... do something with the array
    free(array);
  }
```

you could also allocate on the stack (so you don't need to free manually):

```
  #include <alloca.h>
  void myfun(unsigned int n) {
    mytype_t*array = (mytype_t*)alloca(sizeof(mytype_t) * n);
    // ... do something with the array
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). Use [`malloc`](http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/unix-memory/unix-memory.html#c_alloc) function.

Answer (score 0):

malloc or calloc

```
YourType* ptr = malloc(sizeof(YourType)*NumberOfItemsYouNeed)
```

Comment: [Do ***NOT*** cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!

Comment: @H2CO3 Is that a misdemeanor or a felony? ;-)

Comment: @FiddlingBits It's a deadly sin. :P